# Loop integrals (quantum field theory)

Tags: numerical-integration

I am attempting to compute the one loop contribution to the Higgs mass, and the one loop integral is somewhat difficult. I decided to try and get Mathematica to do it, to see if the answer can point me in the right direction. I inputted,

```
Integrate [(k^(d - 1)*(k^2 + p*k + m^2))/(((k - (x - 1) p)^2 + 
  p^2 (x - x^2 - 1))^2), {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

where the integration variable is $k$, and the rest are constants. Mathematica outputted,

[image]

i.e. it simply wrote out the integral, and did not even attempt to compute it. Can someone tell me why it behaved like this; it's happened with other integrals in the past? How can I make it perform the integral (if it can)? It didn't even output an error message.

PS: Please feel free to edit/improve the tags, the closest I found to integration was 'numerical integration.'

Comment: Your integral seems to behave like `k^d` for large `k`,  just by power-counting. So, you probably want to do some analytic continuation (integration by parts, whatever) from `d` small enough to make this convergent (negative `d`), if you want to use dimensional regularization, or use a different regularization scheme. You can try the integral without specifying the limits, at least you will get some result (in terms of `AppellF1` special function).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Thanks, I got something in terms of hypergeometric functions (AppellF1), as you said.

Comment: Just to let you know, your assertion that *Mathematica* didn't even try to compute the integral is wrong - it tries and can't find a result so it returns the input expression. This is the correct and expected behaviour.

Comment: It would be useful to inspect how the integrand behaves as a function of complex `k`. Thus define `f[k_, p_, m_, x_, d_] := (k^(d - 1) (k^2 + p k + m^2))/((k - (x - 1) p)^2 + p^2 (x - x^2 - 1))^2`, then display contour plots of `Abs[f]` and `Arg[f]` in the complex `k` plane using (for instance) `ContourPlot[#[f[kr + I ki, 1, 1, 1, 4]], {kr, -3, 3}, {ki, -2, 2}, Axes -> True] & /@ {Abs, Arg}`. You can then see how Mathematica represents the function, and it helps you to split up the range of integration so it follows the intended path — e.g. which way to go around singularities.